# how to change the elements inside an object which is inside an array using forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

how do i create a forEach loop for the elements inside the object which is inside an array?

```
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

i have to add an ! for each username

Comment: please make an attempt before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a `multidimensional array`, you have to call the `index` for `username` in order to add the ! sign

```js
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];

array.forEach(element => console.log("!"+element["username"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
array.forEach((item) => {
  item.username = "!"+ item.username
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Javascript forEach` for getting the result in a loop. Check the below code:

```js
const JsonArr = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];

JsonArr.forEach(function(data, index) {
  data.username = '!' + data.username;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he needs

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to modify a key's value inside of an object. You can do it in-place and modify the existing object, or you can create a copy.

---

If you want to modify the items in-place:

```js
const array = [
  { username: "john"  , team: "red"   , score:  5 , items: [ "ball", "book", "pen"     ]},
  { username: "becky" , team: "blue"  , score: 10 , items: [ "tape", "backpack", "pen" ]},
  { username: "susy"  , team: "red"   , score: 55 , items: [ "ball", "eraser", "pen"   ]},
  { username: "tyson" , team: "green" , score:  1 , items: [ "book", "pen"             ]},
];

array.forEach(item => item.username = `!${item.username}`);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to create a copy:

```js
const array = [
  { username: "john"  , team: "red"   , score:  5 , items: [ "ball", "book", "pen"     ]},
  { username: "becky" , team: "blue"  , score: 10 , items: [ "tape", "backpack", "pen" ]},
  { username: "susy"  , team: "red"   , score: 55 , items: [ "ball", "eraser", "pen"   ]},
  { username: "tyson" , team: "green" , score:  1 , items: [ "book", "pen"             ]},
];

const deepCopyAndModify = array.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  username: `!${item.username}`,
  items: [...item.items]
}));

console.log(deepCopyAndModify);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```